# Pulumi - Chart - Failed checking the Kubernetes version: argocd: >= 1.22.0-0 and got Kubernetes 1.20.0

Tags: kubernetes, charts, pulumi

Got an issue in deploying the argo-cd helm chart, it seems failing checking the Kubernetes version: argocd: >= 1.22.0-0 and got Kubernetes 1.20.0

Pulumi is not using the installed Helm on my Mac and seems to have kube-version set to  1.20.0!

Pulumi Chart ressource:

```
    new k8s.helm.v3.Chart(
      'argo-cd',
      {
        chart: 'argo-cd',
        fetchOpts: {
          repo: 'https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm'
        },
        namespace: 'argo',
        values: {}
      },
      {
        providers: {
          kubernetes: cluster.provider
        }
      }
    );
```

Result:

```
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (my-project-prod):
    error: Error: invocation of kubernetes:helm:template returned an error: failed to generate YAML for specified Helm chart: failed to create chart from template: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.22.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart is working as intended. `>=1.22.0-0` means the chart must be rendered with a version of the Kubernetes client greater than 1.22.0.

Check your Helm version is compiled against 1.22.

If you want to render your chart against your cluster's capabilities, use `helm template --validate`. That will tell Helm to pull the Kubernetes version from your cluster. Otherwise it uses the version of Kubernetes the Helm client was compiled against.

You can also refer to this github [link](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/issues/1411) for more troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, and this current answer isn't helpful, since this is running in _pulumi_. It doesn't sound like any local version of helm should matter.